# Is there any way to differentiate what drive is connected to what connection on a MacBook Pro where an SSD is in the optical drive bay?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, macbook-pro

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro where I installed a 960GB SSD in both the HDD space and the old CD drive bay using a caddy.

Now I want to upgrade one of the drives to a 2TB non-SSD hard drive, but I am not sure which one to backup before doing the operation because they look the same in the system report.

One is `disk1s2`, and the other is `disk2s1`, but I think this doesn’t tell you for sure, does it?

Here is an image of my terminal results using `diskutil list`:

[image]

Comment: If you knew the serial number, then System Information should work, but I'm guessing you don't?

Comment: no - i dont.  I was thinking of just backing up both drives and then seeing what happens when I  make the physical changes I want, and restoring accordingly.

Comment: That sounds tedious. It'd probably be easier just to remove the back case (since you're going to have to do that anyways) and check to see the serial number of the drives quickly.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but only because I was willing to take a gamble I was right in guessing, which i was with some luck.